# How to setup REST API routes for CREATE, UPDATE, GET AND DELETE in Express.js?

Tags: api, rest, express, routes

I am building my first "real" MEAN application, and I am playing around with how to structure my REST api, which I would like to use as my backend.

I would like to know how to design the typical API methods in Express:

- GET
- POST
- CREATE
- UPDATE

I have made the following code, which solves the GET, UPDATE and DELETE. But how to implement POST? And is this decent practice?

**Code:**

```
app.get('/api/serials',function(req,res){
    // get all serials code
});

app.get('/api/serials/:id',function(req,res){
    // get by id code
});

app.get('/api/serials/:id/update',function(req,res){
    // update code
});

app.get('/api/serials/:id/delete',function(req,res){
    // delete code
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be missing a fundamental concept here.  A RESTful API responds to requests to the same URI differently, depending on the HTTP method.

```
// So it's NOT this:
app.get('/api/serials/:id/update', updateHandler);
app.get('/api/serials/:id/delete', deleteHandler);

// but rather `PUT` requests for updates
app.put('/api/serials/:id', updateHandler);

// and a `DELETE` requests for deletes
app.delete('/api/serials/:id', deleteHandler);
```

... where all requests that operate on an individual member of a resource collection are sent to the same URI.

Requests that operate on the resource collection are sent to the collection or base URI for the resource:

```
// the READ you already have right
app.get('/api/serials', indexHandler);

// but new resources should be created by POSTing to the collection URI
app.post('/api/serials', createHandler);
```